# SQLZOO Nobel Tutorial #8

Tags: sql

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial

**Can someone give me some help** to do the #8?
I am new to SQL, and I really have no idea why my answer is wrong:

```
select yr from nobel where 
yr in (select distinct yr from nobel where subject='Physics') 
and 
yr not in (select distinct yr from nobel where subject='Chemistry')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All,
I got it solved by myself.

```
select distinct yr from nobel 
where 
subject='Physics' and yr not in 
(select distinct yr from nobel where subject='Chemistry')
```

Thanks

I also find a way to reveal the answer of those questions(at least some of them)
just append     **?answer=1**     to the url, you may be able to get an answer page.
Hope this works!

Answer (score 1):

I got it right by this query:

```
select * from nobel where (yr=1980 and subject='physics') or (yr=1984 and subject='chemistry');
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM nobel
 WHERE (subject ='Physics'
  AND yr='1980') or (subject='Chemistry' and yr='1984')

This is easy and straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select yr,subject,winner 
    from nobel 
    where subject = 'Physics' and yr=1980
union 
select yr,subject,winner
    from nobel
    where subject = 'Chemistry' and yr=1984
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT yr,subject,winner FROM nobel WHERE yr=1980 AND subject NOT IN('Chemistry','Medicine')
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the right answer, logical as well as in readable form:

```
SELECT yr,subject,winner
FROM nobel
WHERE (yr = 1980 and subject like 'Physics') + (yr = 1984 and subject like 'Chemistry')
```

Comment: how does your answer differ to the other answers?

Comment: The Point in my answer is that i have just started learning SQL so i wrote the query in simple language as the question indicated and the result given by the query was right. so just for the beginners i think it is good else may be it can be made more compact or fast.