# SQLZOO Nobel Tutorial #10

Tags: sql

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial

The problem statement is as follows; I am working on SQLZoo Nobel Tutorial #10.

> Show who won a 'Medicine' prize in an early year (before 1910, not
>   including 1910) together with winners of a 'Literature' prize in a
>   later year (after 2004, including 2004)

I am new to SQL, and I really have no idea why my answer is wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM nobel
WHERE ( subject = 'Medicine' AND yr < 1910 )
OR ( subject = 'Literature' AND yr > 2004 );
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Questions need to be self-containing. If you can't even make the effort of putting all necessary info into the question, then probably nobody will make the effort to answer

Comment: Someone will *always* make the effort to answer a question, no matter how little information is provided.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Yeah, I wasn't going to answer because of how bad the question was originally, but I saw quite a few similar questions stemming from SQLZoo on SO. I think people may actually find it useful in the future.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables [...--Drop Table](https://xkcd.com/327/) That just shows the insane dedication of people who frequent the site. and the addictive behaviors caused by the site :P

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or the question you're asking. The name of the off-site tutorial and the exercise number contains no relevant information in regards to your question, and a future reader will find no value in getting 5000 results all titled "SQLZOO Nobel Tutorial #10" in a search. Thanks.

Comment: About the format of the question, I just copied from this one 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772815/sqlzoo-nobel-tutorial-8

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a silly answer, but your only issue is the bounds.

> Show who won a 'Medicine' prize in an early year (before 1910, not
>   including 1910) together with winners of a 'Literature' prize in a
>   later year (after 2004, **including** 2004)

The answer is that you need `>=` on the year for 2004.

```
SELECT *
FROM nobel
WHERE (Subject = 'Medicine' AND YR < 1910)
OR (Subject = 'Literature' AND YR >= 2004)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include 2004 data by adding `=` to your condition

```
SELECT * FROM nobel
 WHERE ( subject = 'Medicine' AND yr < 1910 )
 OR ( subject = 'Literature' AND yr >= 2004 );
```

You have to change

`OR ( subject = 'Literature' AND yr >2004 );`

to

`OR ( subject = 'Literature' AND yr >= 2004 );`